# Wordpress plugin using wp.media to crop images

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, image, plugins

Im using this function in my new Wordpress plugin development, this works ok, using Wordpress Media Uploader for image upload, but I need to use a predefined crop functionality to crop the image after upload and I don't know how do it.

```
function wilson_newsletter_media_library(big_parent){
    var frame_uploader, datos_imagen;
    if ( undefined !== frame_uploader ) {
        frame_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    frame_uploader = wp.media.frames.frame_uploader = wp.media({
        title: "Insert Media",
        button: {
            text: "Aceptar"
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    frame_uploader.on( 'select', function() {
        datos_imagen = frame_uploader.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
        big_parent.children('img').attr("src", datos_imagen.url);
    });

    frame_uploader.open();
}
```

I really apreciate any help.

Comment: Why not? I took it from here: https://www.neoguias.com/usar-wordpress-media-uploader/#comment-30498

Comment: Can I use "WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control" in some way to crop the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a possible solution over on the WordPress Stack Exchange website that shows how to select and crop an image using the Media Library from your Theme Options page:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281760/using-media-uploader-to-select-image-of-specific-size-enforce-cropper/302962#302962